# What's a good starter book on photographer Yousuf Karsh?

Tags: books, photographer

I have recently been very moved by what I have seen/read on the internet about the work of [Yousuf Karsh](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Yousuf_Karsh).

I would really like to get more insight into how he captured the true character of his subjects.

There are plenty of books on [Amazon about Karsh](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=n%3A266239%2Ck%3Akarsh%2Cn%3A!1025612%2Cn%3A91&bbn=1025612&keywords=karsh), but I don't know which might help me to develop the insight I am looking for.

Does anyone know of a good book that would get me started?  (Or any other resource?)

Comment: Not a book, specifically, but visit http://karsh.org for some really good info. His anecdotes are awesome.

Comment: The site is great -- and it is essentially a subset of the *Biography* book. I recognise both the images and the blurbs from the book. (I wish I still had the book -- it's one of those ones you buy for yourself thirty of forty times, and find yourself giving away, still in like-new condition, to people who love it as much as you do. And everyone loves it.)

Comment: @Stan - Yeah, I really liked it. It wasn't a book, so I didn't post as an answer, but I figured it was of interest anyways.

Comment: Thanks, @John.  I've been to the website, and I can see I'll be spending some more time there over the next few days.  :)  Would you post it as an answer?  I did specify "or other resource" in my question, and I think that having it as an answer would make it more findable.

Comment: @AJ - No problem, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Karsh's own book, *Karsh: A Biography in Images*, is about the best there is for that. Beyond the biography, each of the photographs in the book includes a blurb about the reason the portrait was done in a particular way, what the pose, perspective and lighting were meant to capture. It's shy on the technical details if you're looking for "Karsh recipes", but it is a great source of insight into the psychological and iconographical aspects of his work.

Answer (score 3):

Not a book, specifically, but visit [karsh.org](http://karsh.org) for some really good info. His anecdotes are awesome.